Other invariant measures than Lebesgue measure?
Consider a rational rotation of the circle. What are other invariant measures different than the Lebesgue measure?
Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

You might be interested in log-polar coordinates.  (A.k.a. how computer vision ignores rotation of the sought for item.  Rotation in Cartesian space is translation in log-polar coordinates.)

why I should be interested in this?@EricTowers

Hint: If $f:X\to X$ is a function and $x\in X$ is such that $f^p(x)=x$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$, then the average of Dirac measures
$$
\dfrac{\delta_x+\delta_{f(x)}+\cdots+\delta_{f^{p-1}(x)}}{p}
$$
is an $f$-invariant Borel probability measure on $X$.

is there is a reason why the average of Dirac measure has highest power $p-1$?
